# Disable gdmgreeter in RHEL 5?

Tags: redhat, graphical-user-interface, gdmgreeting

I would like to disable the "gdmgreeting" application that is a graphical frontend, as I only want console interfaces. This application runs on vt7 and restarts every time after I manually kill it. I have no desktop environment installed (gnome, kde), so this app just uses memory and CPU for nothing.

What can I do? I couldn't find any initscript or something like that that runs it.

The following processes are causing it to appear:
/usr/bin/Xorg : 0 -br -audit 0 -auth /var/gdm/:0.Xauth -nolisten tcp vt7

/usr/libexec/gdmgreeter

Removing the full graphical frontend is a better solution (x11?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to change /etc/inittab and look for the line with initdefault, and change it from 5 to 3:

```
 id:3:initdefault:
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks.

The following gives also the possibility to delete the X server:

And it works!
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-fedora-linux-disable-remove-x-windows-org/

Nota: change from 5 to 3, not from 4.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I grew up w/ Slackware, where 4 was multiuser w/ X. I just never run RH with the gui, so I took a stab in the dark :)